# the width of my select tag do not want to change

Tags: html, css

I am developing a registration page for an online shopping site.

in my form I have a select tag, it displays very well in the browser but it has a small width as you can see in this picture:

[image: select]

as you can see the width of my select is too small compared to the other inputs, so I want to increase it for which it is equal to those of the input.

I put is code css but it does not work the width of the select does not change :

```
style="width: 5000px;"
```

I want to specify that I use the template aroma I suspect that this template that gives restrictions that prevents me from applying my css but I'm not very sure

here is my code in more detail :

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group" >
     <select class="form-control" name="role" style="width: 5000px;">
          <option value="Simple_utilisateur">Simple utilisateur</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

and this is my all code html :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Bougrine - Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/Fevicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/themify-icons/themify-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/linericon/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/nice-select/nice-select.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/nouislider/nouislider.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!--================ Start Header Menu Area =================-->
    <header class="header_area">
    <div class="main_menu">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand logo_h" href="Acceuil_marjane"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>Bougrine</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse offset" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu_nav ml-auto mr-auto">
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item submenu dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false">Liste des produits</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Jus_marjane">Jus</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Biscuits_marjane">Biscuits</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Yaourt_marjane">Yaourts</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Pc_marjane">Pc portable</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Tel_marjane">Téléphones portables</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Legume_marjane">Légumes</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Fruit_marjane">Fruits</a></li>
                  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Danape_marjane">Danapes</a></li>
                </ul>
         </li>


              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav-shop">
              <li class="nav-item"><button><i class="ti-search"></i></button></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><button><i class="ti-shopping-cart"></i><span class="nav-shop__circle">3</span></button> </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="button button-header" href="#">Se connecter</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
    <!--================ End Header Menu Area =================-->

  <!-- ================ start banner area ================= --> 
    <section class="blog-banner-area" id="category" >
        <div class="container h-100">
            <div class="blog-banner">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="banner-breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Register</li>
            </ol>
          </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!-- ================ end banner area ================= -->

  <!--================Login Box Area =================-->
    <section class="login_box_area section-margin">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="login_box_img">
                        <div class="hover">
                            <h4>Already have an account?</h4>
                            <p>There are advances being made in science and technology everyday, and a good example of this is the</p>
                            <a class="button button-account" href="login.html">Login Now</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="login_form_inner register_form_inner">
                        <h3>Create an account</h3>
                        <form class="row login_form" action="#/" id="register_form" >
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Entre votre nom" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Username'">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="prenom" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email Address'">
                                                        </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="adresse" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Password'">
                                                            </div>
                                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="date_naissance" placeholder="Entrez votre date de naissance" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Confirm Password'">
                            </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="email" placeholder="Entrez votre email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Confirm Password'">
                            </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="password" placeholder="Entrez votre mot de passe" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Confirm Password'">
                            </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmation_password" placeholder="Confirmer votre mot de passe" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Confirm Password'">
                            </div>

                                                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group" >
                                                            <select class="form-control" name="role" style="width: 5000px;">
                                                                <option value="Simple_utilisateur">Simple utilisateur</option>
                                                            </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <div class="creat_account">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="f-option2" name="selector">
                                    <label for="f-option2">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <button type="submit" value="submit" class="button button-register w-100">Register</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--================End Login Box Area =================-->



  <!--================ Start footer Area  =================-->  
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-area footer-only">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row section_gap">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets ">
                            <h4 class="footer_title large_title">Our Mission</h4>
                            <p>
                                So seed seed green that winged cattle in. Gathering thing made fly you're no 
                                divided deep moved us lan Gathering thing us land years living.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                So seed seed green that winged cattle in. Gathering thing made fly you're no divided deep moved 
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Quick Links</h4>
                            <ul class="list">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget instafeed">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Gallery</h4>
                            <ul class="list instafeed d-flex flex-wrap">
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r5.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r7.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                <li><img src="img/gallery/r8.jpg" alt=""></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="single-footer-widget tp_widgets">
                            <h4 class="footer_title">Contact Us</h4>
                            <div class="ml-40">
                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-location-arrow"></span>
                                    Head Office
                                </p>
                                <p>123, Main Street, Your City</p>

                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-phone"></span>
                                    Phone Number
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    +123 456 7890 <br>
                                    +123 456 7890
                                </p>

                                <p class="sm-head">
                                    <span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                                    Email
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    free@infoexample.com <br>
                                    www.infoexample.com
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row d-flex">
                    <p class="col-lg-12 footer-text text-center">
                        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. --></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--================ End footer Area  =================-->



  <script src="vendors/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/skrollr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/nice-select/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendors/mail-script.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the width of that element? Have you tried to use the inspector on the actual element? Maybe some previous `!important` style?

Comment: yes I'm sure I'm applying my css to this element

Comment: Can you perform an inspect of the `select` element (through Chrome) and provide a screenshot of the styling that is being applied on the element? You can do this by right click of the dropdown and selecting Inspect from the context menu that appears.

Comment: That doesn't look like a browsers built in select, are you perhaps applying the style to the real (hidden) `select` but displaying a fake `select` onscreen? (Edit: You look like you're using nice-select, which uses that fake UI method)

Comment: doesn't `.form-control` have `max-width: 100%;`? If you want to adjust the size of your select, adjust the width of your column.

Comment: I added some pictures at the bottom which explains what I have now in my browser I invite you to see them

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using bootstrap. In bootstrap > 4 you can use the class "d-block" so the select box is displayed full width like so:

```
<select class="form-control d-block" name="role">
   <option value="Simple_utilisateur">Simple utilisateur</option>
</select>
```

I would suggest not to use inline css. Why is your width 5000px anyway?

Comment: I put d-block it  works but now I have 2 select one with the right width and the other with a small but I do not understand normally I put only one select why there are two that are displayed in my browser ??

for the 5000px it's just to test normally it will be 350px that's the exact size

Comment: It seems that you are using some hidden select. Are you using a plug-in for that?

Comment: I do not understand what a hidden selection means but what I can tell you is that I work with a template I think that the creators of this template "aroma" it is they who put this

Answer (score 0):

this is what i get when i add d-block :

[image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

I put d-block it works but now I have 2 select one with the right width and the other with a small but I do not understand normally I put a single select why there are two that appear in my Navigator ??